# Insert The Value from 10 radio button list from .aspx page(asp.net) into a single row into the data base

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have 10 radio button list in the .aspx page (in asp.net) ,in the database one Row (name Answer)

1.In the Model Layer ,I mention this code

```
 public class DimensionQuestion
        {
           public string NewCompanyName { get; set; }
           public string NewSurveyName { get; set; }
           public List<int> NewAnswer { get; set; }
        }
```

2.In the Data Layer Layer,I mention this Code,

```
public static bool InsertNewDimAnswer(DimensionQuestion dimension)
       {
           bool result;


           using (var helper = new DbHelper())
           {
               _cmdtext = "sp_InsertNewDimAnswer";

               var success = new SqlParameter("@Success", SqlDbType.Bit, 1, ParameterDirection.Output, true, 0, 0,
                                              "Result", DataRowVersion.Default, 0);

               foreach (string s in dimension.NewAnswer)
               {
                   if (s.Trim().Length > 0)
                   {
                       var parameter = new[]
                                    {
                                        new SqlParameter("@CompanyName", dimension.NewCompanyName),
                                        new SqlParameter("@SurveyName", dimension.NewSurveyName),


                                        new SqlParameter("@Answer",s  ),

                                        success,
                                    };
                       helper.ExecuteScalar(_cmdtext, CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameter);
                   }
               }
               result = (bool)success.Value;
           }


           return result;
       }
```

1. Finally in the Business Layer

   private void FillObjects()
           {
   List Answer = new List();
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer1.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer2.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer3.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer4.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer5.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer6.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer7.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer8.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer9.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer10.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer11.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer12.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer13.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer14.Text.Trim()));
               Answer.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rbAnswer15.Text.Trim()));
               _DimensionQuestion.NewAnswer = Answer;
   }

And on the **Button Click**

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                FillObjects();


                if (InsertData.InsertNewDimAnswer(_DimensionQuestion) 
                {

                    ShowMessage("Information is saved");
                    Reset();

                }
                else
                {
                    ShowMessage("Please try again");

                }
            }

            finally
            {
                //_DimensionQuestion = null;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store it as a semi colon delimited string in the database.

When building the string loop through the radio buttons and then add ; then store the full string in the database.

Then when filling the data back in just split the string by the ; and fill the array/list with each item.